# How can i get collection of custom module in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have created a custom module: Vendor_Faq

My module structure is:

```
Vendor
└───Faq
    │   registration.php
    │
    ├───etc
    │       module.xml
    │
    ├───Model
    │   │   Custom.php

    │   │
    │   └───ResourceModel
    │       │   Custom.php
    │       │
    │       └───Custom
    │               Collection.php
    │
    ├───Setup
    │       InstallSchema.php
    │       
    │
    └───view
        └───frontend
            │___Template
            │       Faq
                        Index.php
            ├───layout
            │       faq_faq_index.xml
            │
```

After the creation of the module, I have written the below code but it's not working.

Below is code with a folder structure:

> /block/Faq/Index.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Faq\Block\Faq;
use Vendor\Faq\Block\BaseBlock;

class Index extends BaseBlock
{
    //public $hello='Hello World';

    protected $mymodulemodelFactory;
    public function __construct(
    \Vendor\Faq\Model\ResourceModel\Custom\CollectionFactory $mymodulemodelFactory, 
    )
    {
        $this->mymodulemodelFactory = $mymodulemodelFactory;
    }
    public function getCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->mymodulemodelFactory->create();
        return $collection;
    }


}
```

AND

get collection data folder structure:

> /View/Frontend/Template Faq.Index.php

```
echo $block->getCollection();
```

but it's not working. After running the code it displays the blank page.

Please suggest a solution?

Comment: plz let me know if you have issue

Comment: just set, $collection = $this->mymodulemodelFactory->create()->getCollection() in your Block  file;

Comment: please show your BaseBlock.php file code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get data using foreach of your collection,

```
class Index extends BaseBlock
{
    //public $hello='Hello World';

     protected $mymodulemodelFactory;
     public function __construct(
       \Ashore\Faq\Block\Context $context,
       \Ashore\Faq\Model\CustomFactory $mymodulemodelFactory
     )
     {
        $this->mymodulemodelFactory = $mymodulemodelFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
     }
    public function getCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->mymodulemodelFactory->create()->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

**in Block file,**

```
$collection = $block->getCollection();
foreach($collection as $moduledata){
    echo "<pre>";print_r($moduledata->getData());
}
```

**Remove var** folder and check.

Comment: Not working ...dislpay blank page

Comment: plz check Block file its correct or not

Comment: not working -display blank page ....plz give me different solution to collection of module data

Comment: i have  set, $collection = $this->mymodulemodelFactory->create()->getCollection() in my Block file but its not working

Comment: i have remove var folder and checked ....but display blank page

Comment: update code of construct function please remove var and check

Comment: BaseBlock code plz check and let me know

Comment: BaseBlock Code check and plz give me any soluction

Comment: i have just update my code in answer please check new code

Comment: which code ....sir

Comment: above answer code, i have update construct function in my answer as above, replace your old code with new code in block file from above

Comment: Add below code sir...But display blank page

Comment: plz any give me soluction?

Comment: i have load all my data in controller its loaded and display frontend .?

Comment: Don't place model/helper/resourcemodel functions in controller files

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Faq\Block\Faq;

use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Vendor\Faq\Block\BaseBlock;
use Vendor\Faq\Model\ResourceModel\Custom\CollectionFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template 
{
    protected $mymodulemodelFactory;
    protected $request;

    public function __construct(
    CollectionFactory $mymodulemodelFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
    RequestInterface $request,
    array $data = [] 
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->mymodulemodelFactory = $mymodulemodelFactory;
    }
    public function getCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->mymodulemodelFactory->getCollection();
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

Hey **@Devidas** I hope It's Work For you

Answer (score 0):

****Try to below code****

```
namespace Vendor\Modulename\Controller\Custom;

Class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $mymodulemodelFactory;
    public function __construct(
       \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
       \Vendor\Modulename\Model\CustomFactory $mymodulemodelFactory
    )
    {
        $this->mymodulemodelFactory = $mymodulemodelFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function getCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->mymodulemodelFactory->create()->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        return $collection;
    }
}
```